# git commands deleted my stuff

Tags: git, github

I am really a beginner to github and git, I had a repository on my github with some base code, and recently I installed a new operating system an backup my application code and added a lot of things to it, when I tried to push the changes to github, I got an error :

```
 [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'root@....git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I searched on line and found a command which I executed :

```
git pull --rebase
```

This caused me another issue and I searched and found another command which I executed as well

```
git pull origin branchname --allow-unrelated-histories
```

another error show up and found another answer which I executed :

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
```

This one removed all the changes I've made on my local computer and replace it with the base code I had in the remote (github) repository

Sorry guys I know ignorance is not bless but now I am asking if there is any way to get my code back ?

Comment: wooow I just posted this 1 seconds and saw someone down voted it right away !!!!! anyway I am not going to deal more with these kind of people, please I need help about this guys

Comment: `git reflog` might help for files/changes that are part of at least some commit. I'm sure there are related questions on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have somehow messed up the `HEAD` of your branch by using `reset --hard`. Use [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to find the last commit you had before you decided to rebase, and then reset to that commit.

```
git reflog -g

# find the commit id which you want to return to using the commit message
# It might contain two commit ids for the same commit message 
# if rebase was successful. Choose the older one.

git checkout -b temp_branch
git reset --hard <found_commit_id>
```

Comment: when I try to merge the temp_branch it says : refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: I don't know why you're facing this error, but you can pass `--allow-unrelated-histories` parameter while merging.  Try to do it on another temp branch so that you don't end up doing something undesirable.

Comment: Why do you use `-g`? I can't find documentation for that option.

Comment: @C-Otto Now come to think of it, out of habit I guess since I couldn't find any documentation for it either. I am used to using `git log -g`, seems I mixed up the commands. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry guys I know ignorance is not bless but now I am asking if there is any way to get my code back?

Well, restore it from your backup. If you do not have it then no, all your **uncommitted** changes are most likely gone. Not necessarily for good as yet the last chance is to shut down the machine immediately, put your HDD to other machine, mount disk as read-only and try to use "undelete" type of tools.

> git commands deleted my stuff

No. You did. By doing things w/o understanding what will be the outcome. Be glad no-one posted `rm -rf /` as a ultimate solution for you to copy and paste... I believe you learned to always do a copy in case something would go wrong. And to to execute unknown commands blindly.

Comment: but if he had commits before hard reset, he can try reflog

Comment: Also, if he had staged but not committed changes, it's possible to search the raw object database for interesting-looking things.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski you made me feeling worst about myself, and lost hope, I solved the issue using hspandher solution, but I learned to not do this ever again. by the way I know linux commands and won't delete the home directory lol

Comment: Glad you managed to recover, Learn the lesson as you were simply lucky this time. As for Linx - I am afraid you just think you do know linux commands :) `rm -rf /` is not deleting your home directory...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the root and everything on it :) I was just happy to see my code back and said home directory, anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

hspandher's answer is true, but i want to add some more info.

You may see the commit id in `git log` too, depend's on what happened with the branch.

Also the first error was a normal merge error,

```
git pull --rebase
```

try to pull the changes from it's upstream, then rebase your changes to the HEAD of the upstream branch, basically it will look like you would have started to work from the last commit, but there can be conflicts during this. It's kinda like a ff merge, but you pulling the remote master in.

Take a look at this: [image]

Now if you work in a team, ask them what is their merge strategy, because there can be huge differences between repos. Also just a rule of thumb, always use own branches if you work with others, you can always merge it back, but screwing up the remote on origin can give someone a nice little fun.